# Is there any way in Scala to have a dynamic number of named/typed parameters?

Tags: scala

I'm working on some Scala code where the user will have a variable number of named variables, all of the same type `A`:

```
val a1: A = getA1()
val a2: A = getA2()
val a3: A = getA3()
// ...
```

I would like to define a class called `Processor` that takes these arguments as parameters, transforms each parameter into a new type `B`, and exposes a method called `process` that gives the user access to these new transformed variables. The best API I've come up with so far is:

```
class Processor(a1: A, a2: A, a3: A) {
  private val b1 = toB(a1)
  private val b2 = toB(a2)
  private val b3 = toB(a3)

  def process(f: (B, B, B) => C): C = {
    f(b1, b2, b3)
  }
}

// Usage:

val a1: A = getA1()
val a2: A = getA2()
val a3: A = getA3()

val p = new Processor(a1, a2, a3)
p.process((b1, b2, b3) => doSomething(b1, b2, b3))
```

The problem with this API is that it only works for three parameters, whereas the user could have anywhere from 1 to 20 parameters. I could define `Processor1`, `Processor2`, `Processor3`, etc classes that take each take a different number of parameters, but this would be a repetitive and ugly API. Another option is to take `A*` as a parameter in both the `Processor` constructor and `process` method:

```
class Processor(a: A*) {
  private val b = a.map(toB)

  def process(f: (Seq[B]) => C): C = {
    f(b)
  }
} 

// Usage:

val a1: A = getA1()
val a2: A = getA2()
val a3: A = getA3()

val p = new Processor(Vector(a1, a2, a3))
p.process((b) => doSomething(b(0), b(1), b(2)))
```

This API works for any number of parameters, but it no longer has type safety or named parameters, so the code could blow up at runtime if the user accidentally looked up an index that did not exist (e.g. `b(3)`). In other words, the compiler no longer verifies that the number of parameters passed to the `Processor` constructor matches the number used in the `process` method.

Is there any way in Scala to have a dynamic number of named/typed parameters? Perhaps using a macro?

Answer (score 3):

With the help of [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless), you can define `Processor` like:

```
class Processor[T](t: T)
 (implicit
   mapper: ops.tuple.Mapper.Aux[T, ToB.type]
 ) {
  private val bs = mapper(t)

  def process[C](f: mapper.Out => C): C = {
    f(bs)
  }
}
```

(`shapeless._` was previously imported.)

It can be used like

```
val p4 = new Processor(a1, a2, a3, a4)
p4.process{case (b1, b2, b3, b4) => ??? }
```

Here, when `Processor` is instantiated with a tuple of `A`s with type `T`, it requires an implicit `shapeless.ops.tuple.Mapper`, that allows to map `toB` (wrapped in `ToB`, see below) on this tuple. The type member `Out` of this implicit is the "output" tuple, made of `B`s. It is used in the signature of `process`.

`ToB` is defined like

```
object ToB extends Poly1 {
  implicit def apply = at[A](a => toB(a))
}
```

and allows to map `toB` on a tuple with `ops.tuple.Mapper`.

Comment: I don't full understand what `ops.tuple.Mapper` is or does. Are there any docs on it?

Comment: Also, in your example, the `Processor` constructor takes just a single parameter, `t: T`. Should it be `t: T*`?

Comment: I'm afraid there's no comprehensive documentation on shapeless. https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#hlist-style-operations-on-standard-scala-tuples illustrates operations on tuples. `Mapper` is the underlying type class of `map` on tuples.

Comment: About `T`, this relies on auto-tupling. In the example, it will be `(A, A, A, A)`. So no `T*`, just `T`.

Comment: FYI, `Mapper` is defined here: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/ops/tuples.scala#L539, and used here: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/syntax/std/tuples.scala#L297.

Comment: Oh wow, I had no idea about auto-tupling. And thanks for the pointer to the Mapper stuff. Let me read through it, see if I can wrap my head around it, and get back to you.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but after staring it for a while, as well as the nearly non-existent docs of Shapeless, I still can't make sense of how to adapt it to my actual case (the code in my original question was obviously a simplified example) and I worry any future maintainer of this solution would be just as confused. Doesn't `Mapper.Aux` take three type parameters? What are the limits on type `T` in `Processor`? Can I use the parameter `t` directly in any way? What if the `toB` method needs other parameters besides the one `a` at a time?